# How to debug/run pytest in GoLand IDE?

Tags: pycharm, ide, pytest, goland

I am trying to run python tests using py.test in stand alone terminal, it works perfectly fine.

But When I try to run the same pytests in GoLandIDE (by selecting the test method , right click -> run as or debug as , the test doesn't work and exits with following output.

Any pointers would be very helpful. Thank you.

```
/usr/bin/python3.7 /home/vagrant/go_workspace/src/github.com/mytests/tests/test_permissions_account.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

```
/usr/bin/python3.7 /home/vagrant/.GoLand2019.2/config/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 46219 --file /home/vagrant/go_workspace/src/github.com/mytest/tests/test_permissions_account.py
pydev debugger: process 21581 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 192.7142.48)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit python default test runner as pytest as shown in picture and ensure that you added all relative paths as sources by marking them explicitly.

OR

Simply download community edition of PyCharm that comes with much more sophisticated ways to infer the relative paths , change the default test runner to pytest.

[image: python-settings]